# How to get BUnit JSInterop?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, blazor-jsinterop, bunit

According to the [BUnit documentation](https://bunit.dev/docs/test-doubles/emulating-ijsruntime.html) this should be available by default.
But in my Unit test `Microsoft.JSInterop` is a namespace, not a class where `Setup` can be called on. I've also tried `BUnitJSInterop`. Am I missing a using? Or something else?

Maybe I need to be in a test context? I'm already writing this code from an XUnit [Fact] attributed method. I don't think BUnit has any context modifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BunitJSInterop` type is member of the `TestContext`, see our [API documentation](https://bunit.dev/api/Bunit.TestContext.html?q=TestContext#Bunit_TestContext_JSInterop).

That said you can easily access the property like this:

```cs
public class MyTests : TestContext
{
  [Fact]
  public void Test001()
  {
    JSInterop.SetupVoid("myfunc", "myarg").SetVoidResult();
```

Your issue might arise as your class is not directly inheriting from `TestContext` but is newed up in your test:

```cs
public class MyTest
{
  [Fact]
  public void Test001()
  {
    using var ctx = new TestContext();
    ctx.JSInterop.SetupVoid("myfunc", "myarg").SetVoidResult();
```